# elasticsearch api in angular 2 application

Tags: api, elasticsearch, logstash, angular-cli

I am not sure , how to use elasticsearch API avaialble in below link in angular application.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html

I have gone through the below sit for using elasticsearch services.But for other functionality like multi field search, conditional search, pagination with first and last pages, i didnt get any idea how to proceed.

http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/angular-4-elasticsearch-example-quick-start-how-to-add-elasticsearch-js#comment-3537

Please kindly share any links or guide me using elastic search in angular cli (angular 2) application.

Answer (score 6):

There is a javascript client available too.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch

```
npm install elasticsearch --save
```

Its typings are available from definitelyTypes

```
npm install @types/elasticsearch --save
```

Then you can directly use in your angular application

Example : 
To create ElasticSearch client

```
...
import { Client } from 'elasticsearch';
...
 this.esClient = new Client({
      host: 'elastic-url'
    });
...
```

everything is there in the official client For features such as pagination, conditional search you have to constuct your query properly before passing.

Example Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
              "param2": "HUMAN"
          }
        },{
          "match": {
            "param1": "param1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Example Usage:

```
 client.search({
        index: 'masterindex',
        body: {
          "size":0,
          "query": esQuery,
          "aggs": aggOBj
        }
      },(error, response)=> {})
```

Comment: Any chance you could put together a stackblitz of this working please?